How to dynamically adjust Container height according to its children?
I'm designing a UI for a chat application when I came up with this problem.
The problem is pretty simple .
I want Either or two things
1.I want to dynamically adjust containers height according to the grid View children.( To Make sure there are no blank space left)
(https://i.sstatic.net/1mDGg.jpg)
2.I want to fit the children of the grid view inside a fixed container height ( To avoid children images being cut off )
(https://i.sstatic.net/TG2Bz.jpg)
This is the specific snippet
Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.3,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.only(
                bottomEnd: Radius.circular(chatBubbleRadius),
                topEnd: Radius.circular(chatBubbleRadius),
                bottomStart: Radius.circular(chatBubbleRadius),
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              color: Colors.white),

          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: GridView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2, // Number of columns
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0, // Spacing between columns
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0, // Spacing between rows
                mainAxisExtent: screenHeight * 0.15,
              ),
              itemCount: 4, // Total number of items
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  child: const Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/image-3.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),

This is the complete widget
class ChatBubbleSenderImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatBubbleSenderImage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double toolBarheight = screenHeight * 0.15;
    double chatBubbleRadius = 15;

    return Column(
      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const CircleAvatar(
              radius: 20,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/profile-1.jpg'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: toolBarheight * 0.1,
            ),
            const Text(
              "Mark Williams",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: toolBarheight * 0.1,
            ),
            const Text(
              "8:16 PM",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: toolBarheight * 0.05,
        ),
        Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.3,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.only(
                bottomEnd: Radius.circular(chatBubbleRadius),
                topEnd: Radius.circular(chatBubbleRadius),
                bottomStart: Radius.circular(chatBubbleRadius),
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              color: Colors.white),

          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: GridView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2, // Number of columns
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0, // Spacing between columns
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0, // Spacing between rows
                mainAxisExtent: screenHeight * 0.15,
              ),
              itemCount: 4, // Total number of items
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  child: const Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/image-3.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: toolBarheight * 0.15,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


Things I've tried so far

I've tried removing height property from Container - Did not work ! ( Threw some rendering layout exceptions which I don't know how to handle )

I've tried giving height and width property to Image - Did not work ! ( No errors thrown , but did not change a thing )

I tried setting mainAxisExtent property - Works to a certain extent, but not perfect , not dynamic

I tried setting childrenAspect propety - same results as above



body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, toolBarheight * 0.5),

          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const Column(
                children: [
                  ChatBubbleSender(),
                  ChatBubbleUser(),
                  ChatBubbleSenderImage()
                ],
              );
            },
          ),





To dynamically adjust the height of the container according to the content of the GridView, you can wrap the GridView inside a SingleChildScrollView. This way, the container's height will automatically adjust based on the size of its content, and there won't be any blank space left. Here's how you can modify your code:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  double toolBarheight = screenHeight * 0.15;
  double chatBubbleRadius = 15;

  return Scaffold(

body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // you can create separate files for this
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/profile-1.jpg'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: toolBarheight * 0.1),
                    Text(
                      "Mark Williams",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: toolBarheight * 0.1),
                    Text(
                      "8:16 PM",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: toolBarheight * 0.05),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(chatBubbleRadius),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                          mainAxisExtent: screenHeight * 0.15,
                        ),
                        itemCount: 4,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: Image(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/image-3.jpg'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: toolBarheight * 0.15),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

Now you can get the widget inside the ListView.builder to a separate file.
This is output you expected


you try this solution.

It still doesn't work
The screen freezes and rendering exceptions are thrown

I update my answer try this

I tried your latest answer , But still didn't work
Maybe its because How I call that these in another file, I've updated that snippet in the question

I don't understand what you are saying. If you create an external file, you can import the file.

What I'm saying is
I call the ChatBubbles in another file .
And there I wrap it in a ListView .
So I was wondering whether the issue would be caused by this as well.
Please look at the new snippet I provided in the Original question.
Maybe thats the issue ?
Please take a look.

do you have three separate files   ChatBubbleSender(), ChatBubbleUser(),ChatBubbleSenderImage(),    you can import it

do you don't know how to call it

Yeah I have them in 3 separate files.
I know how to call it and the issue is not that.
I 'm kindly asking you to take a look at how I call it (Take a look at the latest update)
I wrap the chatbubbles inside a listView.builder (In the body part of the main screen) . Is this the one causing the screen to freeze  ? I have no idea what so ever

Ok that's a mistake in my code. In my code, the error might be caused by the combination of using both Expanded and SingleChildScrollView  widgets inside the Column. I update my code you can try it

It's still not working , I've been trying to solve this issue for 3 days. I can't solve it. Thanks for trying

What is the error showing in your terminal. First copy and past my code. Its working fine you can create step by step seperate files.

Thanks Brother ! , It finally worked.
But I have to separate them into various file
Thanks A lot !
